# Howto design a clock driven multi-agent simulation

Tags: scala, simulation, actor

I want to create a multi-agent simulation model for a real word manufacturing process to evaluate some dispatching rules. The simulation needs to produce event logs to evaluate time effect of the dispatching rules compared to the real manufacturing event logs.

*How can I incorporate the 'current simulation time' into this kind of multi-agent, message passing intensive simulation?*

Background:
The classical discrete event simulation (which handles the time-advancement nicely) cannot be applied here, as the agents in the system represent relatively complex behavior and routing requirements plus the dispatching rules require them to communicate frequently. This and other process complexities rule out a centralized scheduling approach as well.

In the manufacturing science, there are thousands of papers using a multi-agent simulation for their solution of some manufacturing related problem. However, I haven't found a paper yet which describes the inner workings or implementation details of these simulations in the required detail.

Unfortunately, using the shortest process time for discrete time stepping in a system might be infeasible as the range of process time is between 0.1s and 24 hours. There is a possibility my simulation will be used for what-if evaluations in a project later on so the simulation needs to run as fast as possible - no option for overnight simulation runs.

The problem size is about 500 resources and 1000 - 10000 product agents, most of them is finished and not participating in any further communication or resource occupation.

Consequently, in result to the communication new events can trigger an agent to do something before its original 'next time' event would arrive. For example, an agent is currently blocked on a resource lasting an hour. However, another higher priority agent needs that resource right away and asks the fist agent to release that resource.

In some sense, I need a way to create a hybrid of classical message passing agent-simulation and the discrete event simulation.

I considered a mediator agent that is involved in every message - a message router and time enforcer which sends around the messages and the timer tick events. Also the mediator agent keeps a list of next event times for various agents. However, I feel there should be a better way to solve my problem as the concept puts an enormous pressure at the mediator agent.

**Update**

It took a while, but it seems I managed to create a mini-framework and combined the DES and Agent concept into one. I'm sure its nothing new but at least unique: http://code.google.com/p/tidra-framework/ if you are interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem sounds as if it should be tackled by using *parallel* discrete-event simulation - the mediator agent you are planning to implement ('is involved in every message', 'sends around messages and timer tick events') seems to be doing the job of a discrete-event simulator right now. You can make this scale to the desired problem size by using more of such simulators in parallel and then use a synchronization algorithm to maintain causality etc. (see, e.g., [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471183830) for details). Of course, this requires some considerable effort, and you might be better off by really trying out the sequential algorithms first.

A nice way of augmenting the classical DES-view of logical processes (= agents) that communicate with each other via events could be to blend in some ideas from other formalisms  used to describe discrete-event systems, such as [DEVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEVS). In DEVS, each entity can specify the duration it will be in a certain state (e.g., the agent blocking a resource), and will only be interrupted by incoming messages (and then change its state accordingly, e.g. the agent freeing the resource).

BTW In which sense do you think that the agents are too complex to be handled with discrete-event simulation? If you regard each agent as a logical process, it doesn't really matter how complex it is from a simulation point of view - or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: Thank you. You are right about this problem is closer to DES. I might have misphrased that sentence.  My work is part of a research project where my colleges do the DES based simulation. I've got the task to find out and implement an agent based approach to the underlying problem. The DES guys however do not plan to include that kind decision making or optimalization I want to achieve with my simulation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and the refernces.

Comment: +1 for the BTW part, I don't see how it could be too complex for DES